# Get back focus from child window to parent window without closing child window( in mfc visual studio )

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

How to provide control back to parent window from child window . (Just like "find" window in notepad++) in visual studio mfc application.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your are launching another (Child) window from current(Parent) window, simply call setFocus() of parent window:

```
GetParent()->SetFocus()
```

Comment: where exactly its crashing. GetParent returning null value?

Comment: I am putting this "GetParent()->SetFocus()" inside child's mouse double click event.

Comment: show your code. I cant imagine your condition. check getparent() return value

Comment: Blindly setting focus on a window is a sure recipe for disaster. If you are unlucky, that window is disabled. And now you broke *all* keyboard navigation. That's a usability issue for most, and fatal in those cases, where no pointing device is attached.